# Custom Jenkins slave in Kubernetes doesn't have install apps

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile setup in an internal project that uses a custom `jenkins/slave` build where I add nvm and Node 12 to perform the build.  The custom image is in an internal Harbor instance I have running within my Kubernetes cluster.  Everything seems to start fine, until it starts performing the pipeline steps.  All the folders/files/applications I installed as part of my custom `jenkins/slave` is missing.

The Dockerfile for my `jenkins/slave` looks like this:

```
FROM jenkins/slave

MAINTAINER xxx

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev curl apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
RUN apt update && apt install docker-ce-cli

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir /version_1.2.0

USER jenkins
RUN which node
RUN which npm
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
RUN echo $PATH
```

And my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'jenkins-slave-build'
      yaml """
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins-slave-build
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jenkins-slave
    image: harbor.mydomain.com/library/custom/jenkinsslave:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    tty: true
  restartPolicy: Never
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        echo 'Testing..'
        sh 'ls -lart /'
        sh 'npm --version'
        sh 'node --version'
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

When I run the pipeline I can see it pull the image from Harbor, it prints what looks like a correct YAML for the pod in the console output for the build, and I can see the pod spin up in Kubernetes if I do a `kubectl get pods --watch`.  In my Jenkinsfile I try to do an `ls` at root, which should contain a folder `version_1.2` but that folder is missing.  Also I tried doing `npm --version` and `node --version`, but those fail saying the apps are not installed.  My current thinking is that the pipeline is running on the Jenkins master, not the slave pod.  I also tried using just the `node:12.16.1` docker image as well, but that had the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

To those looking at this in the future...it seems that the Jenkins slaves have their volumes mounted over when they run??? At least, that's what a few posts I found seemed to suggest.  This explains why my installed tools are not there, and why my root folder is missing the test "version_1.2" folder I made there.

To fix the NPM issue I simply had to install the NodeJS Plugin (the one that says "NodeJS Plugin executes NodeJS script as a build step." in the description), configure the NodeJS install in Global Tools, then add:

```
tools { nodejs: "whatever_you_called_it_in_global_tools" }
```

This will cause the version of NodeJS you configure to be installed in the slave prior to running.  I am still missing make and docker, so my CI/CD is still not 100%, but I am certain those 2 issues are similar and I just need to figure out which plugins add make and the docker cli and get those installed as well.

**Edit**
Working on this more, I have come to a better solution to the above than to force the tool installation.  It appears that by surrounding the `step`s in `container('label') { ... }`, where "label" is the label you give your agent, causes it to work.

I am still stuck, however, in getting Docker to tag and push the images up to my internal Harbor server, but that's another issue.